# Запуск приложения на wildFly

Tags: java, nginx, wildfly, war

У меня есть проект на java 1.8, который собирается в `.war` и потом запускается через `wildFly`, все конфиг файлы уже потаскал у коллег но ничего не помогает, 3 дня гуглежки тоже не помогли.

Суть проблемы что при запуске standalone в `cmd` такой текст:

```
"Calling "D:\wildfly-12.0.0.Final\bin\standalone.conf.bat"
Setting JAVA property to "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\bin\java"

===============================================================================

  JBoss Bootstrap Environment

  JBOSS_HOME: "D:\wildfly-12.0.0.Final"

  JAVA: "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\bin\java"

  JAVA_OPTS: "-Dprogram.name=standalone.bat -Xms64M -Xmx2G -XX:MetaspaceSize=96M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djboss.bind.address=10.11.13.53 -Djboss.bind.address.management=localhost -Djboss.bind.address.private=10.11.13.53"

===============================================================================
```

и все, на этом весь процесс стопорится.

Если запускать голый `wildFly` без билда, то он стартует и все окей, но дело похоже в билде, а куда копать я не знаю, т.к. устроился неделю назад.

По технологиям это БД в докере, `artemic` в докере, билд локальный и `wildFly`, и ещё `nginx`.